# how to prevent a key input from appearing in input field?

Tags: javascript, web-frontend

I am trying to validate user input in a text input field.

I have written a javascript function for the same purpose which fires on `onkeyup` event.

The goal is to only allow user input if it's a numeric value less than `100` and with at most `1` decimal place.

The function is working fine but if a enter an invalid character ,say `'a'`, it will flash in the input box before being removed.

What I want is that if the entered character violates the defined condition it should not appear in the input box (as it is flashing right now for a split second).

Here's my code:

```
function validatePercent(event) {
    var txt = $("#tds_input").val();
    //  alert(event.source);
    if (!parseInt(txt)) {
        $("#tds_input").val('');
    }
    if (isNaN(txt / 1)) {
        txt = txt.substr(0, txt.length - 1);
        $("#tds_input").val(txt);
    }
    if (txt > 100) {
        //alert(2);
        txt = txt.toString();
        txt = txt.substr(0, txt.length - 1);
        $("#tds_input").val(txt);

    }
    txt = txt.toString();
    if (txt.indexOf('.') > -1) {
        if (txt.substr(txt.indexOf('.') + 1, txt.length).length > 1) {
            txt = txt.substr(0, txt.length - 1);
            $("#tds_input").val(txt);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `onkeydown` instead?

Comment: does calling `preventDefault()` on the event stop the character from appearing? (I'm not sure, but it would be the first thing I'd try.)

Comment: @RobinZigmond: I tried that...didn't work...

Comment: @ChrisG: i tried that...but it changes the behaviour of the code and doesn't work...

Comment: @RobinZigmond  but wouldn't that also stop the user from using the key AT ALL? I.e. preventing the c would also prevent ctrl+c, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Erch - good point (although it should only do that if the input has focus at that point - but that's still not great UX). Was just thinking out loud, and apparently it doesn't work anyway :)

Comment: i am not sure about standard html, since i only used frameworks up to now, but is there a way to extend you input control? thats how i'd do it in a framework

Comment: @Erch:would be great if you can suggest a way in jquery..

Comment: to my knowledge jquery doesn't offer ui controls... sorry not to be of more help

Comment: @Erch: any chance for angularjs..? Thanks for the time and effort....

Comment: @VijayKumar Check my answer bellow. I fixed it. Seems to include what you require.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

You could store the value of the when the focus is in the input.

When the user enters a valid percentage (integer only), replace the value stored. When inputs is incorrect, just replace with the old value.

```js
var decimalSeparator = 1.1.toLocaleString().replace(/\d/g, ''),
     
    pattern1 = "^(\\d{1,3})?([",
    
    pattern2 = "]?\\d{1})?$",
    
    regex = new RegExp(pattern1+decimalSeparator+pattern2),

  resetContent = function () {
           $('#tds_input').val($('#tds_input').data('val'));
         }, 
                  
    matchRegex = function (value) {
     return value.match(regex);
  };

$('#tds_input').bind('focusin', (e) => {
 $('#tds_input').data('val', $('#tds_input').val());
});


// handle input (keys, paste)
$('#tds_input').bind('input', (e) => {

  let txtValue = $('#tds_input').val();
  
  // input is empty
  if (txtValue === "") {
   $('#tds_input').data('val', "");
    return;
  }

  // value does not match regex
  if (!matchRegex(txtValue)) {
    // maybe it ends with the decimal character?
    if (txtValue[txtValue.length - 1] === "." && txtValue !== "100.") {
     
      // simulate the user enters a decimal next
      if (matchRegex(txtValue + "1")) {
       $('#tds_input').data('val', txtValue);
          return;
      }
    } 
    resetContent();
    return;
  }
  
  // check between 0 and 100
  let value = parseFloat(txtValue);
 
  if (value >= 0 && value <= 100) {
  
    // store new valid number
    $('#tds_input').data('val', value);
    // put the value as an integer in the input
    
    $('#tds_input').val(value);
    return;
  } else resetContent();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="tds_input"/>
```

Comment: In your solution,If u enter an alphabet after a digit the conditions are violated...

Comment: @VijayKumar thanks! It looks like I did not paste the good version of the fiddle and the code. I will update my answer. Feel free to comment back.

Comment: @VijayKumar How can you do this? I am not able to reproduce. What do you type in?

Answer (score 0):

Using `type=number` (and not `text`) can help

```js
function validatePercent(event)
 {     
  var txt=$("#tds_input").val();
    if(!parseInt(txt))
    {
        $("#tds_input").val('');
    }
   if(isNaN(txt/1))
   {
    txt=txt.substr(0,txt.length-1);
      $("#tds_input").val(txt);
   }
  if(txt>100)
  { 
      txt=txt.toString();
      txt=txt.substr(0,txt.length-1);
      $("#tds_input").val(txt);

  }
  txt=txt.toString();
  if(txt.indexOf('.')>-1)
  {
      if(txt.substr(txt.indexOf('.')+1,txt.length).length>1){
      txt=txt.substr(0,txt.length-1);    
      $("#tds_input").val(txt);
  }
  }

 }
```

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" id = "tds_input" onkeyup="validatePercent()">
```

Comment: No it doesnt..."type" number would never let you enter numbers!

Comment: @Abhishek: your solution works if i input a non-digit character but as i said the input should be less than 100..so if i enter 103, 3 still appears for a moment...also if i enter 10.34, 4 will also flash for a moment..Any ideas for that...?

Comment: @Abhishek Look, I'm typing a random letter in your textfield after running the snippet, and it's easily visible for half a second. Firefox. It does work in Chrome, but not everybody uses webkit browsers.